# Time scale with single object - bar isn't centered (chart.js)

Tags: javascript, chart.js

When I'm using time scale for x-axis and pass only one object to data, the bar isn't centered, and label is skewed https://jsfiddle.net/t1edj73g/

When I pass two or more objets - everything is fine.

Also, I've tried to add `bounds: 'ticks'` option. But in this case extra label is automatically adding to x-axis.

What is the problem with passing only one object?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a poor workaround, but adding an empty datapoint `{}` after the existing datapoint seems to be doing the trick...

```
    data: [
    {
      x: new Date('2019-01-09T00:00:00+03:00'),
      y: 10,
    },
    {}
    ],
```

Comment: I've just tried this workaround on my example, but nothing has changed. Can you provide link to jsfiddle, please?

Comment: This is what I get, when I follow your link http://joxi.ru/82Q51lVtwjo0q2
The bar is still not centered, and label is still skewed